# Cannot catch exception

Tags: python, exception

I have the following code:

```
def coming_episode ( show ):
    try:
        show = api.search ( show , 'en' ) [ 0 ]
    except:
        print "a"
        return

    announced = [ 'show title' ]

    for e in show [ len ( show ) -1 ]:
            if e.FirstAired != '' and time.time () < time.mktime ( e.FirstAired.timetuple () ):
                    announced.append ( [ e.EpisodeName , e.id , time.mktime ( e.FirstAired.timetuple () ) ] )
    return announced
```

And this works fine when I look for a show which exsists in the TVDB api. However, I also want to catch the exception when I type something stupid, such as "awdawd" as a show.

I tried `except:` and also `except TVDBIndexError:` but both still give me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "init.py", line 27, in <module>
    series                  = coming_episode ( series )
  File "init.py", line 19, in coming_episode
    for e in show [ len ( show ) -1 ]:
  File "/Users/Sites/Python/_envs/Series/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytvdbapi/api.py", line 340, in __getitem__
    raise error.TVDBIndexError("Season {0} not found".format(item))
pytvdbapi.error.TVDBIndexError: (u'Season 0 not found', (), {})
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: your trace indicates the exception is being thrown on the for loop, *not* on `api.search`. What are you  trying to iterate over?

Comment: You use pytvdbapi, right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not specifying that...

Answer (score 4):

I guess you use [pytvdbapi](https://github.com/fuzzycode/pytvdbapi), so I took all my informations from [here](https://github.com/fuzzycode/pytvdbapi/blob/master/pytvdbapi/api.py).

When you use

```
for e in show [ len ( show ) -1 ]
```

you iterate over each episode of a *single* season of the show.

When a show has 3 seasons, you iterate over (`len(show) == 3`, `3 - 1 == 2`) the 2nd season.

If a show has exactly one season, the season you try to iterate is `len(show) == 1` => `1 - 1 = 0` => `0`, but there's no season `0`, only a season `1`, so an error is raised. (I don't know for sure, but maybe if a show is not found there's still a `Show` instance with an empty `Season` instance).

You probably want to use:

```
for s in show:      # for each season in show
    for e in s:     # for each episode in season
        if e.FirstAired != '' and time.time (...
```

Comment: But iterations start at 0 right?
So if the api returns `show = [ 'show1' ]` you'll get "show1" by calling show[0]. Or am I misunderstanding you?

I just want the last episode of the last season.

Comment: Yes, I think so (I didn't test this myself, I just read the source code). The `Show` class has an member called `seasons` where the seasons are stored, and it's a `dict`, not a list. So if you access `show[i]` you don't get the season at *index* `i`, but rather the value of the `seasons`-dictionary with the *key* `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... It suddenly works. Copy pasted the code just now on different machine, and it works. Weird stuff...